# Alternatives to Flash?

Tags: flash, banner

I need to make a flash banner. A really simple banner. But I don't have the Flash app. I'm looking for a free app alternative for flash to run in Macintosh.

I could also be a on-line alternative like: http://www.bannersnack.com/. But free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here:

- http://www.123-banner.com/creator.php?ba=p
- http://www.banner-generator.net/en/bannergen.php
- http://bannermakersite.com/
- ...

or here: https://www.google.de/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=creating+free+flash+banner+online ;)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.123-banner.com/ and http://www.flashbannernow.com/ are my favorite ones